# Deployment Descriptor in Servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

I've just started learning servlet and JSP. What is a Deployment Descriptor(eg. web.xml) in a web application and how is it useful? Detailed explanation is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @jmail Please make sure your edits are substantial and correct. The last ones I've seen aren't. Can you try to improve on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will be going to help as following link as:

[**click:1**](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor-examples/)

[**click:2**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml)

[**click:3**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html)

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't hurt to do a cursory search first:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncbj/index.html

Comment: thanks for the URL, atleast now I have a basic understanding. looking forward to learn in much more detail.